# merge same name multiple part pdf files by order

Tags: bash, pdf

how merge same name's pdf files

1. poetry_2.pdf
2. poetry_3.pdf
3. poetry_4.pdf
4. metaphysics_2.pdf
5. metaphysics_3.pdf

i look for

- poetry.pdf
- metaphysics.pdf

failed this loop to check pdf files and merge with pfunite

```
for file1 in *_02.pdf ; do
    # get your second_ files
    file2=${file1/_02.pdf/_03.pdf}
    # merge them together
    pdfunite $file1 $file2  $file1.pdf
    
done
```

Comment: So `poetry[0-9]*.pdf` should become one pdf? like only `poetry.pdf`? Same goes to `methaphysics[0-9]*.pdf` ? What about `rhetorics` ? What should happen to that file? Could you please clarify the input and output you desired besides the code you provided.

Comment: rhetrorics only one file should not  affected

Comment: Please update your post/question and clarify.

Comment: Is it clear  the question now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a list of prefixes (e.g. `poetry`, `metaphysics`). Then, iterate over that list and unite `prefix_*.pdf` into `prefix.pdf`.

Here we generate the list of prefixes by searching for files ending with `_NUMBER.pdf` and removing that last part. This assumes that filenames do not contain linebreaks.

```
printf %s\\n *_*.pdf | sed -En 's/_[0-9]+\.pdf$//p' | sort -u |
while IFS= read -r prefix; do
  pdfunite "$prefix"_*.pdf "$prefix.pdf"
done
```